# Can't create many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entites with a many-to-many relationship.  `Company` and `SearchKeyword`.

Here are the models:

```
class SearchKeyword
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual OtherDetail OtherDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SearchKeyword> SearchKeywords { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to add a SearchKeyword to a company but it won't let me.  I tried this:

```
using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
{
    Company c = db.Companies.Single(x => x.ID == 1);
    SearchKeyword sk = db.SearchKeywords.Single(x => x.ID == 1);
    c.SearchKeywords.Add(sk);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

It says `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`  I am not sure what is null.  In inspector I can see `c` and `sk` both have full values.  I guess I must be missing a fundamental of how the many-to-many relationship works with EF.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `SearchKeywords` is null.

Either you can assign a List to it before adding a new instance

```
using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
{
    Company c = db.Companies.Single(x => x.ID == 1);
    SearchKeyword sk = db.SearchKeywords.Single(x => x.ID == 1);
    c.SearchKeywords = new List<SearchKeyword>();
    c.SearchKeywords.Add(sk);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or you can do it constructor method

```
class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        SearchKeywords = new List<SearchKeyword>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual OtherDetail OtherDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SearchKeyword> SearchKeywords { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes.  Stackoverflow implements a time limit before such actions are possible.  I will do so once I am able.